# Converting a mySQL table with id's to a MongoDB table with _id's

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I'm transferring a MySQL table to MongoDB. There is a primary key `id` in my MySQL table and I want this `id` to be converted to the `_id` in MongoDB.

I use php's `MongoCollection::insert( $mysql_array );`

However it doesn't work because if I set `$mysql_array['_id']` it is seen by mongo as a String instead of a MongoId. I tried `$mysql_array['_id'] = new MongoId( $id )` but it doesn't allow me to override the default `_id` value. I saw that all my MySQL's integer columns are converted to string by `MongoCollection::insert()`. If I could set `MongoCollection::insert()` to correctly transfer an integer it would maybe work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typecast the _id to a integer value like this...

(int) $mysql_array['_id']

You'll find yourself doing this a lot in mongoDB

Answer (score 1):

The `ObjectId` is a special type in Mongo, but the `_id` property doesn't have to be of this type. You can't coerce a string or number into an `ObjectId`, and you shouldn't.

I assume the problem as you perceive it is that your `insert` worked, but when you looked at the data in the database the `_id` property didn't look like `_id: ObjectId("1234")` (if the original ID was 1234). This is as it should be, and it's perfectly fine.

The idea with `ObjectId` is that it has a predefined structure that makes it guaranteed (mostly) to be unique across a Mongo cluster, but this also means that it has to have this structure, otherwise it is not an `ObjectId`.

You also mention that all your integer columns are converted to strings. PHP and PHP libraries, are notoriously sloppy when it comes to types, so make sure that it's not the case that the values are already strings when they come from the MySQL result set. Worst case you have to explicitly cast the values before inserting them into Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to convert an arbitrary String value into an Mongo ObjectId due to its specific characteristics (12 bytes -> 24 chars generated from 4 bytes timestamp, 3 bytes client hostname, 2 bytes PID, 3 bytes inc value).

Either you abandon using the MongoId type in your collection's _id-fields and use your MySQL-ID as a string instead (which is not a problem and makes the most sense) or you let Mongo to generate the documents' _id for you, which is also a suitable solution if you want to be able to use the MongoId functions (assuming you're working with PHP):
[The MongoId class](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.mongoid.php)

Choosing the second solution you still are able to store your MySQL-IDs in another field of the doc, like *id* or *mysql_id* to reference them later.

Concerning your question about (int) and (string) values: Are you sure they come as a PHP integer from your MySQL DB? If so, they usually should be stored as integers in Mongo. Check it with a var_dump() and in case of incompatibility cast it with an (int). Maybe it would be helpful if you post your select/insert code...

Answer (score 0):

Use `MongoCollection::save()` and your array should work.